# App engine getting operational error: could not connect

Tags: django, google-app-engine, python-2.7

i have a python/django application on google appengine with cloud sql as a backend, i have been getting these `OperationalError: could not connect: ApplicationError: 1 Transient error,please try again.` exceptions occasionally. i want to  know what causes these errors and a quick solution to solve this problem.
the stack trace i am getting is

```
 Following are the exception stacktrace details:
 Traceback (most recent call last):

 File "/base/data/home/apps/myapp/2.382853299895889191/django/core/handlers/base.py",  
 line 111, in get_response
      response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

 File "/base/data/home/apps/myapp/2.382853299895889191/django/views/generic/base.py",  
 line 48, in view
      return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

 File
 "/base/data/home/apps/myapp/2.382853299895889191/django/views/generic/base.py",  
 line 69, in dispatch
      return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)

 File "/base/data/home/apps/myapp/2.382853299895889191/murthy_views.py",  
 line 370, in get
      cartd = cart.Add(cartd, catalogid, item.quantity,item.redeem)

 File "/base/data/home/apps/myapp/2.382853299895889191/classes.py",  
 line 2488, in Add
      cart_item = CartItem(catalog_id)

 File "/base/data/home/apps/myapp/2.382853299895889191/classes.py",  
 line 3789, in __init__
      self.FillItem(item_id)

 File "/base/data/home/apps/myapp/2.382853299895889191/classes.py",  
 line 3810, in FillItem
      if not
 product_list:

 File "/base/data/home/apps/myapp/2.382853299895889191/django/db/models/query.py",  
 line 130, in __nonzero__
      iter(self).next()

 File "/base/data/home/apps/myapp/2.382853299895889191/django/db/models/query.py",  
 line 118, in _result_iter
      self._fill_cache()

 File "/base/data/home/apps/myapp/2.382853299895889191/django/db/models/query.py",  
 line 892, in _fill_cache
      self._result_cache.append(self._iter.next())

 File "/base/data/home/apps/myapp/2.382853299895889191/django/db/models/query.py",  
 line 291, in iterator
      for row in compiler.results_iter():

 File "/base/data/home/apps/myapp/2.382853299895889191/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py",  
 line 763, in results_iter
      for rows in self.execute_sql(MULTI):

 File "/base/data/home/apps/myapp/2.382853299895889191/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py",  
 line 823, in execute_sql
      cursor = self.connection.cursor()

 File "/base/data/home/apps/myapp/2.382853299895889191/django/db/backends/__init__.py",  
 line 319, in cursor
      cursor = util.CursorWrapper(self._cursor(), self)

 File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/storage/speckle/python/django/backend/base.py",  
 line 276, in _cursor
      self.connection = Connect(**kwargs)

 File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/storage/speckle/python/django/backend/base.py",  
 line 201, in Connect

 return driver.connect(**kwargs)

 File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/storage/speckle/python/api/rdbms.py",  
 line 813, in __init__
      self.OpenConnection()

 File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/storage/speckle/python/api/rdbms.py",  
 line 836, in OpenConnection
      response = self.MakeRequest('OpenConnection', request)

 File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/storage/speckle/python/api/rdbms.py",  
 line 943, in MakeRequest
      response = self.MakeRequestImpl(stub_method, request)

 File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/storage/speckle/python/api/rdbms_apiproxy.py",  
 line 69, in MakeRequestImpl
      raise OperationalError('could not
 connect: ' + str(e))
 OperationalError: could not connect: ApplicationError: 1 Transient error,  
 please try again.
```